# Ground disappeared when using Cycle Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am very new to Blender and just downloaded a campfire scene from https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/Gepz/campfire-diorama-blender-scene

I am totally confused that the ground will disappear in cycle viewpoint/render (you can still select it, but can't see anything)

The render visibility is all enabled and nothing is hided. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, if it's copyright free, maybe share it? Maybe it's a driver problem (do you use AMD?) but if it was you shouldn't be able to see the other objects either...

Comment: The floor uses an image to drive its transparency but that image has been mapped with the wrong UV map. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `UVMap`node's  `From Instancer` option, it messes up with the UV used for the image driving the alpha of the ground:

[image: UvMap node]

[image: zommed out]

`From Instancer` maps the image using the UV of the object's parent. This option only works for Cycles as stated in the official [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html#properties) and doesn't do anything in EEVEE. That's why the problem is not visible in EEVEE.

It may be an error from the one that made the scene but this option should not be ticked in this case (since we are supposed to use the object's own UV Map and not another object's). Of course, it wouldn't have mattered since he created the scene to be rendered in EEVEE but that's even more reason to leave it alone (I say that but I honestly do not know why he checked that option in the first place, may be he has his reasons).

Just uncheck it (it will use the object's UV map instead) and the ground will appear:

[image: unchecked] [image: ground is visible]